# MySQL - retrieve a value from another table if column is null

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let's say I have a table setup with a few values, including a name, an ID, and a foreign key that references the ID of another table. The name can be null. When I select all the records from this table, I want to get the name if it is not null. If it is, I want to get the name of the record referenced by the foreign key. I am able to modify the database structure if necessary, or I can simply change the query. What are my options?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use [`IFNULL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) or [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce):

```
SELECT T1.ID, IFNULL(T1.name, T2.name) AS name
FROM firsttable T1
LEFT JOIN secondtable T2
ON T1.T2_id = T2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ISNULL` for `sql`

```
SELECT T1.ID, ISNULL(T1.name, T2.name) AS name
FROM firsttable T1
LEFT JOIN secondtable T2
ON T1.T2_id = T2.id
```